# Tag mismatch player health

Tags: pawn

I'm trying to get the health of a player but I'm getting a tag mismatch error on the code below.

```
new health;
GetPlayerHealth(playerid, health);
```

Hopefully someone can help me, this is important to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in SA:MP (which I presume is what you're developing for). GetPlayerHealth gives the player's health as a float, but you're saving it as an untagged variable.

To fix this, simply change `new health;` to `new Float:health;`

Comment: And yes I am samp scripter